# How can I programmatically expand/collapse and select an item in a tree?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtreeview

Let's say I added a TreeView widget called `treeView` in Qt Designer and I'm using this code to add a few items to it:

```
class StandardItem(Qt.QStandardItem):
    def __init__(self, txt='', font_size=11, set_bold=False, color=Qt.QColor(0, 0, 0)):
        super().__init__()
        fnt = Qt.QFont('Open Sans', font_size)
        fnt.setBold(set_bold)
        self.setEditable(False)
        self.setForeground(color)
        self.setFont(fnt)
        self.setText(txt)


model = Qt.QStandardItemModel()
rootNode = model.invisibleRootItem()
A = StandardItem("A")
A.appendRows([StandardItem("1"),StandardItem("2"),StandardItem("3")])
B = StandardItem("B")
B.appendRows([StandardItem("1"),StandardItem("2")])
rootNode.appendRows([A,B])
self.treeView.setModel(model)
```

How can I write a function that collapses/expands item `A`? And how can I write a function that selects item `A`, as if it has been clicked? I might be missing something in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expansion and selection are tasks that affect the visual part so they must be handled by sight. The first task is done through the [`setExpanded()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#setExpanded) method and the second using the [`select()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#select) method of the [`selectionModel()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel) associated with the view, in both cases the QModelIndex associated with the item is used:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import Qt


class StandardItem(Qt.QStandardItem):
    def __init__(self, txt="", font_size=11, set_bold=False, color=Qt.QColor(0, 0, 0)):
        super().__init__()
        fnt = Qt.QFont("Open Sans", font_size)
        fnt.setBold(set_bold)
        self.setEditable(False)
        self.setForeground(color)
        self.setFont(fnt)
        self.setText(txt)


class MainWindow(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.treeView = Qt.QTreeView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.treeView)

        self.model = Qt.QStandardItemModel()
        rootNode = self.model.invisibleRootItem()
        A = StandardItem("A")
        A.appendRows([StandardItem("1"), StandardItem("2"), StandardItem("3")])
        B = StandardItem("B")
        B.appendRows([StandardItem("1"), StandardItem("2")])
        rootNode.appendRows([A, B])

        self.treeView.setModel(self.model)

        index_A = A.index()

        self.treeView.setExpanded(index_A, True)
        self.treeView.selectionModel().select(index_A, Qt.QItemSelectionModel.Select)


def main():
    app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Note:**

It seems that the [`index()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#index) function of the QStandardItem has a bug since it sometimes returns invalid QModelIndex for valid QStandardItem.

```py
print(A.child(0).index().isValid())
```

Output:

```
False
```

This is caused because when the child was added, the "A" was not part of the model then the model is null in those children, as can be seen with.

```
print(A.child(0).model())
```

Output:

```
None
```

If instead "A" are added to the model first and then the children are newly added, then the model is passed.

```py
self.model = Qt.QStandardItemModel()
rootNode = self.model.invisibleRootItem()
A = StandardItem("A")
B = StandardItem("B")
rootNode.appendRows([A, B])

A.appendRows([StandardItem("1"), StandardItem("2"), StandardItem("3")])
B.appendRows([StandardItem("1"), StandardItem("2")])

print(A.child(0).model())
print(A.child(0).index().isValid())
```

Output:

```
<PyQt5.QtGui.QStandardItemModel object at 0x7fb40aa868b0>
True
```

In that case it is better to use the [`indexFromItem()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#indexFromItem) method of QStandardItemModel:

```py
self.treeView.selectionModel().select(
    self.model.indexFromItem(A.child(0)), Qt.QItemSelectionModel.Select
)
```

Comment: Thanks, one more question: Why doesn't this work to select the first child of `A`? `self.treeView.selectionModel().select(A.child(0).index(), Qt.QItemSelectionModel.Select)`

Comment: @Cecemel It seems you have found a bug, see my update